# Does there exist a metric on $X$ such that $X^{∗} − X$ is uncountable?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X^{∗}$ denote the completion of the metric space $X$. Is there a metric on the open interval $X = (0, 1)$ generating the Euclidean topology for which $X^{∗} − X$ is uncountable? Any idea and hint would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the "topologist's sine curve" in the form
$$C=\{(x,\sin(1/x):0<x<1\}.$$
This is a subspace of $\Bbb R^2$ homeomorphic to $(0,1)$, so we can think
of $(0,1)$ as a metric space by considering the metric of $C$ inside $\Bbb R^2$.
Thus
$$d(x,y)=\sqrt{(x-y)^2+\left(\sin\frac1x-\sin\frac1y\right)^2}.$$
The closure of $C$ in $\Bbb R^2$ is the completion of $C$ with respect
to this metric, and contains the uncountable set $\{(0,y):-1<y<1\}$.
Thus $C^*-C$ is uncountable.